# Pass parameter in custom IRouteConstraint

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I saw in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#route-constraint-reference) that I can pass parameter to certain built-in route constraint like `minlength(value)` . How I can achieve the same behaviour with custom IRouteConstraint ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution: it seems that we simply need to pass this parameter in the constructor.

For exemple:

```
public class TestRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public TestRouteConstraint(int parameter)
    {
    } 

    ...
}
```